# Connect application to postgresql cluster using tls

Tags: postgresql, go, ssl, kubernetes, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I have sucecssfully installed a crunchy data postgres cluster with tls certificates from cert-manager on kubernetes by following this tutorial.
https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/using-cert-manager-to-deploy-tls-for-postgres-on-kubernetes

`kubectl -n postgres-operator get secrets`

```
NAME                           TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-w7mnw            kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      45h
pgo-token-9t7dw                kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      45h
pgo-root-cacert                Opaque                                2      45h
hippo-repl-tls                 kubernetes.io/tls                     3      45h
hippo-tls                      kubernetes.io/tls                     3      45h
hippo-instance-token-mmxfj     kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      45h
hippo-00-5klh-certs            Opaque                                4      45h
hippo-00-rsvm-certs            Opaque                                4      45h
hippo-pguser-hippo             Opaque                                7      45h
hippo-ssh                      Opaque                                3      45h
hippo-pgbackrest-token-hcp7m   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      45h
```

Most of these secrets contain something to do with tls for example hippo-tls contains a "ca.crt", "tls.crt", "tls.key" and the pgo-root-cacert secret contains a "root.crt", "root.key". Im not sure which one to use for connecting my application to my database.

This is my deployment yaml for my application

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: admin-app
  namespace: postgres-operator
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: admin-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: admin-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: admin-app
          image: localhost:32000/wtl-admin3.2:registry
          env:
          - name: CA_CERT
            valueFrom: {secretKeyRef: {name: pgo-root-cacert, key: root.crt}}
          - name: TLS_CERT
            valueFrom: {secretKeyRef: {name: hippo-tls, key: tls.crt}}
          - name: TLS_KEY
            valueFrom: {secretKeyRef: {name: hippo-tls, key: tls.key}}
#          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "100Mi"
              cpu: "100m"
```

This is my first time working with tls so im not really sure how to connect with it. This is my Golang postgres connection file.

```
package infastructure

import (
        "context"
        "crypto/tls"
        "crypto/x509"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"

        "github.com/go-pg/pg/v10"
        "github.com/go-pg/pg/v10/orm"
)

func ConnectTls(ctx context.Context) *pg.DB {
        cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(os.Getenv("TLS_CERT")), []byte(os.Getenv("TLS_KEY")))
        if err != nil {
                log.Printf("failed to load client certificate: %v", err)
                log.Println(err)
                panic(err)
        }

        CACertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
        CACertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(os.Getenv("CA_CERT")))

        tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
                Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
                RootCAs:            CACertPool,
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                // ServerName:         "localhost",
        }

        opt := &pg.Options{

                Addr:      "hippo-primary.postgres-operator.svc:5432",
                User:      "hippo",
                Password:  "1XNrN1H-AF)=S(U_9*6(A0V7",
                Database:  "hippo",
                TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
        }
        DB := pg.Connect(opt)
        if err := DB.Ping(ctx); err != nil {
                log.Print("failed to connect")
                log.Print(err)
        }
        return DB
}
```

I've tried to connect using the different secrets in the postgres operator namespace but i usually get the same error about not using tls. I'm also not sure what the ServerName should be for the tls config.

`kubectl -n postgres-operator logs admin-app-b7d97764d-lkrqn`

```
2021/09/03 17:48:46 failed to connect
2021/09/03 17:48:46 pg: SASL: got "SCRAM-SHA-256-PLUS", wanted "SCRAM-SHA-256"
panic: pg: SASL: got "SCRAM-SHA-256-PLUS", wanted "SCRAM-SHA-256"
```

Comment: You say you get an error about not using tls, but the error you show doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: https://github.com/go-pg/pg/issues/1483  I think this article mentions that the error is caused by Postgres wanting tls connections.

Comment: I upgraded go-pg to the latest version and im now getting the error "pg: SASL: got 'S', wanted '\x00'"

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to go-pg v10.10.5 solves this.